# Ruby on rails without using scaffold and generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new user to ruby on rails. 
I have some question please give the answer as early as possible

1) Is it possible to create web application without using ***rails new application_name*** command? means creating  required folder and file manually?

2) I want to create application without using scaffold and generator, so everything is created manually...I searched but not get a link to do it...

Comment: In case you have received answer to your question, please mark appropriate post as answer.

Answer (score 8):

You really should be using `rails new (appname)` to generate your project directory.

From there, you do not need to generate a scaffold. If you want to go slightly less abstract and create some things manually you can use `rails generate resource (resource name)`.

If you want to go even less abstract then that, you can use `rails generate model (model name)` and `rails generate controller (controller name)` and `rails generate migration (migration name)`. Within this level of abstraction, you can specify options such as methods you want the model to have or columns you want the migration to add.

And the least abstract(most manual) would be if you make these files yourself (like actually going in and creating new folders/files for models, controllers, etc.)

So on an order from most abstract to least:
1) generate scaffold
2) generate resource
3) generate model/controller/migration
4) creating the files/folders without rails

Most developers are usually working with the #2, #3, or #4 layers (remember it is always a tradeoff between eliminating a lot of time off by not having to manually create the same code over and over again and flexibility).

Comment: ok..Thanks for giving all detail level of doing application. But right now i want to go by using 4th level of abstraction so any link/pdf which gives total flow of creation file/folder....Thanks You...

Answer (score 2):

`rails new app-name` creates tons of files and folders which are necessary for the app to run. You would waste tons of time writing them yourself. Read as "reinventing the wheel".

You can simply create a controller and view file. Add the corresponding route. Start the server. Voila. You will have it. Most intro-articles showcase Scaffold to show the power of Rails i.e how much can be achieved with few lines of code.